# why sfunction in onReset was called 2 times in GWTP?

Tags: gwtp

i want my web app to show a dialog box after the web app got started. I used:

```
protected void onBind(){
   super.onBind();
   DialogBox dg=new DialogBox();
   dg.show();
}
```

but it didn't work.

So i put the cose into `onReset`

```
protected void onReset() {
    super.onReset();
    DialogBox dg=new DialogBox();
    dg.show();
}
```

this time it showed ok, but it showed 2 dialogboxes instead of 1?

How to fix this problem in GWTP?

Answer (score 0):

i think some certain function called my presenter that i didn't know so the onReset was called 2 times.

I fixed, i put into `onReveal`, & it's ok